# Convert csv time format

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to convert the time format from CSV file like "21-03-2019 00:10:00" to "2019-03-21 00:10:00" I spent hours on this finally still doesn't work hope you all guys can point out my wrong place.

This time I am using Python 3

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/dongmintian994410/Downloads/Data/FM02.csv', header=0)

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    row = data.iloc[i]['Date Time']
```

now I can print out the first row which including the time array however I don't know how to continue .

I would like to convert the time format like "21-03-2019 00:10:00" to "2019-03-21 00:10:00"

Comment: Please properly format your code.

Answer (score 0):

from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/dongmintian994410/Downloads/Data_Capiatalwater/FM002 2.csv', header=0)

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    row = data.iloc[i]['Date Time']

```
datetime_str = row

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

print(datetime_object)
```

finally, I figured this out